# QML Propertyanimation x and anchors fill parent

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have two files, main.qml and object.qml

int main, i have predefined a size and a properyanimation to my object.qml id, in order to slide it in x axis. Its working:

main.qml

```
Rectangle {
    visible: true
    width: 920
    height: 500
    color: "white"
    id: contenedor

...

PropertyAnimation {
        id: slide
        property: "x"
        target: object
        to: contenedor.width
        easing.type: Easing.InQuad
        duration: 1000
    }
}
```

object.qml

```
Rectangle {
    visible: true
    id: object
    x:0
    y:0
    width: 920
    height: 500
    color: "pink"

}
```

When i quit width and height from object.qml and replace it to anchors.fill: parent in order to make object.qml responsive, my Propertyanimation is no longer working... ¿Do you know why?

object.qml

```
Rectangle {
    visible: true
    id: object
    x:0
    y:0
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "pink"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have it.

**object.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    visible: true
    id: object
    x:0
    y:0
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    color: "pink"    
}
```